# NullReferenceException in save game function

Tags: unity, c#

I was making save system to save position of player.

I get an exception:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

It comes from this line: `FloatPos[0] = DataG.transform.position.x;`

Here is my Save Manager:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class SaveManger
{
    public float[] Player, Top, Ground, ET, ED;
    public int PN, PCN;

    public SaveManger(SaveGame SaveGame)
    {    
        PosMath(Player, SaveGame.PlayerPos);
        PosMath(Top, SaveGame.TopPos);
        PosMath(Ground, SaveGame.GroundPos);
        PosMath(ET, SaveGame.EfTop);
        PosMath(ED, SaveGame.EFDown);


        PN = SaveGame.TransformMover.GetComponent<TransformMover>().PuzzleNumper;
        PCN = SaveGame.TopPos.GetComponent<PuzzleSetUp>().PuzzleCloneNumper;   
    }

    public void PosMath(float[] FloatPos, GameObject DataG)
    {
        FloatPos[0] = DataG.transform.position.x;
        FloatPos[1] = DataG.transform.position.y;
        FloatPos[2] = DataG.transform.position.z;
    }    
}
```

Here is my saved game component:

```
public class SaveGame : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject PlayerPos,TopPos,GroundPos,EfTop,EFDown,TransformMover;

    public void Start()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/GSave.GSF";
        if(File.Exists(path))
        {
            LoadButton();    
        }
        else
        {   

        }           
    }

    public void SaveButton()
    {
        SAVESYSTEM.VoidSaver(this);

    }

    public void LoadButton()
    {
        SaveManger Data = SAVESYSTEM.LoadSave();

        TransformMover.GetComponent<TransformMover>().PuzzleNumper = Data.PN;
        TopPos.GetComponent<PuzzleSetUp>().PuzzleCloneNumper = Data.PCN;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialize your `float[] Player` array, so it holds an initial value of `null`.

When you then try to set `FloatPos[0] = DataG.transform.position.x;`, with `FloatPos` pointing to `Player` which is still `null`, that means `null[0] = ...` - but `null` doesn't have a 0th element to assign! It's just nothing.

So, initialize your arrays!

```
public SaveManger(SaveGame SaveGame)
{
    Player = new float[3];    
    PosMath(Player, SaveGame.PlayerPos);

    Top = new float[3];
    PosMath(Top, SaveGame.TopPos);

    Ground = new float[3];
    PosMath(Ground, SaveGame.GroundPos);

    // ...
```

(You might have fallen out of the habit of doing this because in Unity `MonoBehaviour` or `ScriptableObject` scripts, public arrays or lists of serializable types are initialized to an empty array by default by Unity's serialization systems)

This is a basic programming problem that does not require game development specific expertise to solve, so [please remember to search on StackOverflow first](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D%20nullreferenceexception&mixed=1) - you'll find lots of existing answers that explain this in depth. Ask here when your problem is unique to games.

Comment: yas you are right I thought it was default by Unity's Thank you

Comment: Note that even Unity's default wouldn't save you here, because it will default to 0 length, and you're trying to assign 3 entries. Also, the deserializer runs after the constructor, where here you're trying to write the values inside the constructor, before even the deserializer could initialize them for you. So that code is broken in any context.

Comment: What is the deserializer ؟

Comment: [Please remember to search first](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html)